# How to use jq to provide ungrouped result (i.e. parent and children attributes separately)?

Tags: json, select, jq

There is a JSON which I am getting with a script:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "type": "physical",
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "CISCO",
          "description": "test",
          "id": 53,
          "min_max_policy": {
            "legal_hold": 0,
            "name": "child 1",
            "max": 60,
            "min": 0
          },
          "name": "child 1",
          "parent_id": 1,
          "parent_name": "parent 1",
          "system_id": 1,
          "system_name": "cisco 1",
          "version": "None"
        },
        {
          "type": "CISCO",
          "description": "test",
          "id": 54,
          "min_max_policy": {
            "legal_hold": 0,
            "name": "child 2",
            "max": 60,
            "min": 0
          },
          "name": "child 2",
          "parent_id": 1,
          "parent_name": "parent 1",
          "system_id": 2,
          "system_name": "cisco 1",
          "version": "None"
        }
      ],
      "type": "network devices"
    }
  ],
  "machine_type": "X32",
  "min_max_policy": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "parent 1",
    "max": 60,
    "min": 0
  },
  "name": "parent 1",
  "system_id": 1,
  "system_name": "sys 1 name",
  "version": "1.0"
},
{
  "type": "physical",
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "HP",
          "description": "test",
          "id": 55,
          "min_max_policy": {
            "legal_hold": 0,
            "name": "child 3",
            "max": 60,
            "min": 0
          },
          "name": "child 3",
          "parent_id": 2,
          "parent_name": "parent 2",
          "system_id": 3,
          "system_name": "hp 1",
          "version": "None"
        }
      ],
      "type": "network devices"
    }
  ],
  "machine_type": "X32",
  "min_max_policy": {
    "id": 2,
    "legal_hold": 0,
    "name": "parent 2",
    "max": 60,
    "min": 0
  },
  "name": "parent 2",
  "system_id": 2,
  "system_name": "sys 2 name",
  "version": "1.0"
},
{
  "type": "physical",
  "machine_type": "X32",
  "min_max_policy": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "parent 3",
    "max": 60,
    "min": 0
  },
  "name": "parent 3",
  "system_id": 3,
  "system_name": "sys 3 name",
  "version": "1.0"
}
]
}
```

It has 3 parent objects and children. For example, "parent 1" has 2 children, "parent 2" has 1 and "parent 3" has 0.

How to format this JSON with jq to display it in such way:

```
{
"name": "child 1",
"parent_name": "parent 1",
"system_name": "cisco 1"
}
{
"name": "child 2",
"parent_name": "parent 1",
"system_name": "cisco 1"
}
{
"name": "parent 1",
"parent_name": null,
"system_name": "sys 1 name"
}
{
"name": "child 3",
"parent_name": "parent 2",
"system_name": "hp 1"
}
{
"name": "parent 2",
"parent_name": null,
"system_name": "sys 2 name"
}
{
"name": "parent 3",
"parent_name": null,
"system_name": "sys 3 name"
}
```

?

I have tried some options but jq is grouping parent and children. I can't find a way how to display it in the mentioned way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the ordering, the following jq program produces the desired output, as shown below:

```
..
| select(.name? and .system_name?)
| {name, parent_name, system_name}
```

#### Transcript

```
$ jq -f program.jq input.json
{
  "name": "parent 1",
  "parent_name": null,
  "system_name": "sys 1 name"
}
{
  "name": "child 1",
  "parent_name": "parent 1",
  "system_name": "cisco 1"
}
{
  "name": "child 2",
  "parent_name": "parent 1",
  "system_name": "cisco 1"
}
{
  "name": "parent 2",
  "parent_name": null,
  "system_name": "sys 2 name"
}
{
  "name": "child 3",
  "parent_name": "parent 2",
  "system_name": "hp 1"
}
{
  "name": "parent 3",
  "parent_name": null,
  "system_name": "sys 3 name"
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I am getting such result: {
  "name": "parent 1",
  "parent_name": null,
  "system_name": "sys 1 name"
}
{
  "name": [],
  "parent_name": [],
  "system_name": []
}
{
  "name": "child 1",
  "parent_name": "parent 1",
  "system_name": "cisco 1"
}
{
  "name": [],
  "parent_name": [],
  "system_name": []
}

Comment: Information about parents is missing: jq '.data[].children[].children[] | select(.name? and .system_name?) | {name, parent_name, system_name}'
{
  "name": "child 1",
  "parent_name": "parent 1",
  "system_name": "cisco 1"
}
{
  "name": "child 2",
  "parent_name": "parent 1",
  "system_name": "cisco 1"
}
{
  "name": "child 3",
  "parent_name": "parent 2",
  "system_name": "hp 1"
}

Comment: I am getting the required result. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please delete the two earlier comments so others aren’t confused, as neither indicates anything useful.